# Setting different backgrounds for nsview

Tags: macos, cocoa, background, calayer, nsview

I'm trying to set custom background for an NSView. I need different backgrounds to be set based on some action. So i created 2 CAlayers for this view and trying to  fill it using colorWithPatternImage.Is this a right method? If not, how can i do it?

Regards,

LS Developer

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass the view that you want, and in its drawRect: method do something like

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    // Colour the background
    [[NSColor orangeColor] set];
    NSFillRect (dirtyRect);

    // Now draw the parent
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```